# Python 3.5.2 Try Except Invalid Syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax, except

I am receiving an Invalid Syntax error on my except statement.  The code runs fine until I add in the except

```
import pyautogui
print('Press Ctrl-C to quit.')
while True:
     pyautogui.click(1624, 967)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('\nDone.')
```

I'm sure I'm just missing something silly.

Thank you!

Comment: Well... it's because that's invalid syntax. Consider putting that `pyautogui.click` call in a try block... that's where the `except` should go. Don't forget to `break`.

Comment: Except without a try is like else without an if.

Comment: @AlanLeuthard More like `elif`; `else` works with `while` and `for` as well :)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add `try` statement.

```
import pyautogui
print('Press Ctrl-C to quit.')

try:
    while True:
        pyautogui.click(1624, 967)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('\nDone.')
```